# How to check if Pull Request is approved

Tags: github-actions

I have a workflow that runs unit tests whenever a Pull Request is created or changed.

```yaml
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - Release
      - Production
      - Development
    types:
      - opened
      - reopened
      - synchronize

jobs:
  runTests:
    runs-on: [self-hosted]
    if: github.event.review.state != 'APPROVED'
    steps:
      # Run Tests

  requestReReview:
    runs-on: [self-hosted]
    if: github.event.review.state == 'APPROVED'
    steps:
      # Request Re-Review
```

If the Pull Request was previously approved, I want to automatically request re-review and skip running the tests.

I want to skip running the tests to save time on our runners, since the tests take a pretty long time to run, and we only have a few runners available.

I have tried using `if: github.event.review.state == 'APPROVED'`, but this appears to only work for `on: pull_request_review`, but I am using `on: pull_request`.

Is there a way to check the review state of the Pull Request when using `on: pull_request`?

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the current review decision via API:

```bash
gh pr view NUMBER --json reviewDecision --jq '.reviewDecision'
```

which you have to run in a separate step. Something like this:

```yaml
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - Release
      - Production
      - Development
    types:
      - opened
      - reopened
      - synchronize

jobs:
  checkReviews:
    runs-on: [self-hosted]
    outputs:
      reviews: ${{ steps.reviews.outputs.state }}
    steps:
      - id: reviews
        env:
          pr: ${{ github.event.number }}
        run: |
          state=$(gh pr view "$pr" \
              --repo "$GITHUB_REPOSITORY" 
              --json reviewDecision \
              --jq '.reviewDecision')
          echo "state=$state" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"

  runTests:
    runs-on: [self-hosted]
    needs: checkReviews
    if: needs.checkReviews.event.review.state != 'APPROVED'
    steps:
      # Run Tests

  requestReReview:
    runs-on: [self-hosted]
    needs: checkReviews
    if: needs.checkReviews.event.review.state == 'APPROVED'
    steps:
      # Request Re-Review
```

In case you don't have the GitHub CLI available, you could also use curl:

```bash
curl -L \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $GITHUB_TOKEN" \
  -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
  "https://api.github.com/repos/$GITHUB_REPOSITORY/pulls/$pr"
```

with a `run` step where `GITHUB_TOKEN` is set in the environment, and `pr` is set as above.

Comment: When I try that I get `+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException` & `The term 'state=$(gh pr view "$pr" --json 
reviewDecision --jq '.reviewDecision')' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable 
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.`

Comment: @Tyler Oh, you're using a Windows-based runner. I'm assuming hosted runners on Ubuntu, where the GitHub CLI is pre-installed. If you can modify your self-hosted runner, i'd recommend adding the GitHub CLI, and if not, you could query with curl.